# SFML Collision with tilemaps

Tags: c++, sfml

My current method of doing it is to check against my array and make cases for each different value I get. It works for small maps with only 1 or 2 collidable tiles but if I have over 100 I'd have to create over 100 cases and if the player enters another map I'd have to create more cases which is very inefficient. Is there a better way I can do tilemap collision with the player?

For example

```
int x = player.getPlayerPositionX() / map.getTileWidth();
int y = player.getPlayerPositionY() / map.getTileHeight();

switch (player.getDirection())
{
case 3:
    if (map.data[x + y * map.getMapWidth()] == 1)
    {
        player.moveRect(1.0f, 0);
    }
    break;
case 4:
    x = (player.getPlayerPositionX() + 20) / map.getTileWidth();
    if (map.data[x + y * map.getMapWidth()] == 1)
    {
        player.moveRect(-1.0f, 0);
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make cases"? Could you please provide some code to illustrate your current approach?

Comment: How do you store your tilemap? Give us some code showing your current implementation

Comment: @Omni edited to show example.
I store my tilemap in a vector

Comment: You show a `case` statement for 2 player movement directions not for collidable tiles; your code does not match your question description.

Comment: sry my english is not that good I meant for the if statements
for example if my the value in my vector is 1 then stop the player from moving into it. But if I had more collidable tiles I would have to do it for more values in my vector. So if I had up to 100 different collidable tiles I would have to have an if statement for every single one of them.

Comment: No just a loop over all the collidable tiles (that takes the players position) and returns `true` when you find the 1st collision or `false` for no collisions.

Comment: @Tomm You store a single `int` in your tilemap-vector. Why dont you instead create a `struct` that contains information about a single tile (e.g. the type of tile to draw, if it has collision, etc), and store that in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a tile in a game should be flagged as passable or impassable. There is no need to check for every possible case.

```
struct Tile {
    bool passable;
};

bool collision(tileMap, playerCharacter) {
    if(tileMap[playerCharacter.x][playerCharacter.y].Tile != passable) {
        //some collision logic here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about [space partitionning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning). In your case, if you have tiles that have a known size, and are stored in a grid (2d array); you can use integer divisions (of your player coordinate by the tile width) to determine the index in the grid to check your collisions. For "conservativeness" you check the neighbors too, so that you are sure to span the size of the player and check activated tiles. I implemtented mutiple versions of that in extreme carnage, you can refer to the source in the zip https://sourceforge.net/projects/extremecarnage/ there is a binary tree version for landscape construction, and a grid/tile version for enemy storage partitionning